# I am getting and error in Python django code where when i RUN python3 manage.py runserver it raise exception

Tags: python, django

[ss containing the error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63Qov.png)`raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))`
`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:` The included URLconf 'Mysite.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import."

Project name is Mysite and the app name is market

My Url.py file:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from market import views



urlpatterns = [
    #path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('', views.index_one, name='index_one'),

    #path('confirm_order', views.confirm_order, name="confirm_order"),

    path('confirm', views.confirm, name='confirm'),

    path('payment_success', views.payment_success, name='payment_success'),

    path('home', views.home, name='home'),

    path('index',views.index,name='index'),

    path('advertisement',views.advertisement,name='advertisement'),

    path('save_product',views.save_product, name="save_product"),

    path('advertisement_new',views.advertisement_new,name='advertisement_new'),

    path('advertisement_one',views.advertisement_one,name='advertisement_one')
]
```

Settings.py file

```py
        ROOT_URLCONF = 'Mysite.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Mysite.wsgi.application'
```

My views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
```

## Create your views here.

from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.shortcuts import redirect, render

from pip._vendor import requests

from market.models import Product

from datetime import datetime

from btcpay import BTCPayClient

import json, pprint

def index(request):

```
_products = Product.objects.get(order_status='CONFIRMED').order_by('-id')[:5]

_mainVideo = _products[:1]

_slider = _products[1:]

return render(request, 'index.html', {'main': _mainVideo, 'slider': _slider})
```

def index_one(request):

```
try:

    _products = Product.objects.get(order_status='CONFIRMED').order_by('-id')[:5]

    _mainVideo = _products[:1]

    _slider = _products[1:4]

except Product.DoesNotExist:

    _mainVideo = None

    _slider = None



return render(request, 'index_one.html', {'main': _mainVideo, 'slider': _slider,'n': range(4)})
```

def home(request):

```
_products = Product.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:5]

_mainVideo = _products[:1]

_slider = _products[1:]

return render(request, 'index_new.html', {'main': _mainVideo, 'slider': _slider})
```

def payment_success (request):

```
return render(request, 'payment_success.html',{'postdata':request.POST})
```

def advertisement(request):

```
return render(request,'advertisement.html')
```

def advertisement_new(request):

```
return render(request, 'advertisement_new.html')
```

def advertisement_one(request):

```
return render(request, 'advertsement_one.html')
```

def confirm(request):

```
return render(request,'confirm_order.html')
```

def save_product(request):

```
price = 0.00

charge = {}

if len(request.POST) > 0 and request.POST.get('title') != "":



    if request.POST.get('que_type') == "Big Video":

        price = 2.00

    elif request.POST.get('que_type') == "Small Video":

        price = 1.00



    client = BTCPayClient.create_client(host='https://mybtcpay.local', code="zR1R3nG")


    charge_info = {

        "name": request.POST.get('que_type'),

        "description": request.POST.get('que_type'),

        "local_price": {

            "amount": price,

            "currency": "USD"
```

},

```
        "pricing_type": "fixed_price",

        "redirect_url": "http://localhost:8000/payment_success"

    }

    charge = client.charge.create(**charge_info)



if len(request.POST) > 0 and request.POST.get('title') != "":



    product = Product(title=request.POST.get('title'),description=request.POST.get('description'),

                    order_no=charge.code, email_id=request.POST.get('email_id'), username=request.POST.get('username'),

                    amount=price, video_url=request.POST.get('video_url').replace("watch?v=", "embed/"),

                    que_type=request.POST.get('que_type'),created_at=datetime.now())

    product.save()



return render(request, 'advertsement_one.html', {def get_products(request):

_products = Product.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:5]

_mainVideo = _products[:1]

_slider = _products[1:]

return render(request, 'index.html',{'main':_products,'slider':_slider})
```

'checkout':charge,'postdata':request.POST})
def get_products(request):

```
_products = Product.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:5]

_mainVideo = _products[:1]

_slider = _products[1:]

return render(request, 'index.html',{'main':_products,'slider':_slider})
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
```

## Create your models here.

class Product(models.Model):

```
title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
video_url = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
que_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
created_at = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
updated_at = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
email_id = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
username = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
order_no = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
amount = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
order_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
order_completed_date = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
is_deleted = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
  class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'product'
```

Comment: @Alasdair wrt your suggestion i have edited the above qstn and provided the file u mentioned. Please see to it

Comment: I can’t spot the issue in the views you posted. It might be in the models. Posting the full traceback might help. It’s a good idea to add views one by one and use version control to save each step. Then, when you get an error like this, it’s easier to find the problem.

Comment: Ok i am posting the full traceback @Alasdir

Comment: The traceback doesn’t show the problem. It might be models.py is causing a circular import.

Comment: Should I show You that @Alasdair

Comment: If you want us to look at it, yes ;)

Comment: @Alasdair included .

Comment: I can't spot anything in that models. Have you included the *full* `models.py`, `urls.py` and `views.py`? If so, then I'm out of suggestions. Try switching back to an earlier working version of the code and change it gradually until you get the error. Then you'll know where the problem is.